# Are there parameters such that a combinatorial $(n_s,m_t)$ configuration does not exist?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-designs, finite-geometry

It is well known that given a $(n_s,m_t)$ configuration the following must hold:

$$ms=nt$$
$$s(t-1)+1\leq m$$
$$t(s-1)+1\leq n$$

However, for example, a $(43_7,43_7)$ configuration would be an order 6 projective plane but none such exists.

What is known about parameters that satisfy the above conditions but still do not produce a combinatorial configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This paper covers what I was looking for:

https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-21/issue-1/The-Impossibility-of-Certain-Symmetrical-Balanced-Incomplete-Block-Designs/10.1214/aoms/1177729889.full

Comment: Good reference. It will be helpful if you could give a short exposition on how it relates to your problem (to future readers without having to click on the link).